# The polynomial interpolation of degree 4

Tags: numeric, numerical-methods, linear-interpolation

For the provided data set, write equations for calculating the polynomial interpolation of degree 4 and ﬁnd the formula for f by hand.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = f(x) = [5, 31, 121, 341, 781]
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try https://math.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

The pyramid of iterated differences is

```
  5    31   121   341   781
    26    90   220   440
       64   130   220
          66    90
             24
```

You can extend the table by setting the last line constant `24` and computing backwards or you could read off the coefficients of the Newton interpolation polynomial. Anyway, the extended value table for `x=-3..10` is

```
[61, 11, 1, 1, 5, 31, 121, 341, 781, 1555, 2801, 4681, 7381, 11111]
```